# SQLite command line shell stuck on ...> , CTRL+D not working

Tags: sqlite, command-line

I've just started learning Databases, and the instructor is teaching SQLite with the command line shell. I downloaded sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3350400.zip from sqlite.org/download

When I enter false commands, like the first two you can see, I get the correct error messages. But when I enter a syntax error: ("Steve, 87654) for example, it's stuck on ...> waiting for more input. 
After searching on the internet, users suggested the solution "CTRL+D", but it doesn't work for me. CTRL+C however just exits sqlite3.

My question: How do I get out of ...> to continue with my commands? Why CTRL+D doesn't work for me, to get out of the ...> because of the syntax error or other possible causes? How do I fix my problem?

```
C:\Users\myUser>sqlite3 test.db
SQLite version 3.35.4 2021-04-02 15:20:15
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> SELECT * FROM contacts;
Tim|654321|tim@email.com
Brian|1234|brian@mygmail.com
sqlite> INSERT INTO contacts VALUES("Steve", 87654);
Error: table contacts has 3 columns but 2 values were supplied
sqlite> INSERT INTO contacts VALUES(Steve, 87654);
Error: no such column: Steve
sqlite> INSERT INTO contacts VALUES("Steve, 87654);  // Intentional for demonstration //
   ...> ^D  // Entered CTRL+D //
   ...> ;
   ...>     // Entered CTRL+C //
Error: unrecognized token: ""Steve, 87654)"

C:\Users\myUser>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the SQLite command-line shell, all SQL commands must be terminated with a semicolon, but not all semicolons terminate a command.

When you are inside a string or a quoted identifier, you must enter the closing quote (`'` or `"` or `]`).
(And when you are inside a trigger body, you must enter the closing `END`.)

Ctrl+D works only on Unix-y systems. On Windows, use Ctrl+Z (or F6) followed by Enter. (But these, like Ctrl+C, quit the program.)